# Memcached `stats` Command

Tags: memcached

I started `memcached` as a daemon with 512MB of memory.

`memcached -d -m 512`

Then, I telnet'd to the box, and ran the `stats` command.

Why does the `limit_maxbytes` field equal `536870912`? I would've expected `512,000,000`.

```
STAT limit_maxbytes 536870912
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because -m 512 means 512MB and that is 512*1024*1024.